# Python type hinting for async function as function argument

Tags: python, pycharm, python-asyncio, type-hinting

I am trying to make sure a function parameter is an async function.
So I am playing around with the following code:

```
async def test(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

def consumer(function_: Optional[Coroutine[Any, Any, Any]]=None):
    func = function_

consumer(test)
```

But it doesn't work.

I am presented with the following error during type checking in PyCharm:

```
Expected type 'Optional[Coroutine]', got '(args: Tuple[Any, ...], kwargs: Dict[str, Any]) -> Coroutine[Any, Any, None]' instead
```

Can anyone give me some hints how to solve this?

Comment: What happens if you pass `test()` into `consumer`?  According to python 3.7  `type(test)` is `function`, while `type(test())` is `coroutine`, despite `test` being a coroutine and pyre-check finding no errors in your code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can't help you too much, especially because right now (PyCharm 2018.2) this error is not raised in Pycharm anymore.

At present, type hints are somewhere between reliable metadata for reflection/introspection and glorified comments which accept anything the user puts in. For normal data structures this is great (my colleague even made a validation framework based on typing), but things get more complicated when callbacks and async functions come into play.

Take a look at these issues:

https://github.com/python/typing/issues/424 (open as of today) - async typing
https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3028 (open as of today) - var-args callable typing

I would go with:

```
from typing import Optional, Coroutine, Any, Callable


async def test(*args, **kwargs):
    return args, kwargs


def consumer(function_: Optional[Callable[..., Coroutine[Any, Any, Any]]] = None):
    func = function_
    return func


consumer(test)
```

I don't guarantee they meant exactly that, but my hint is built like this:

`Optional` - sure, can be `None` or something, in this case:

`Callable` - something which can be invoked with `()`, `...` stands for any argument, and it produces:

`Coroutine[Any, Any, Any]` - this is copied from OP, and very general. You suggest that this `function_` may be `await`-ed, but also receive stuff `send()`-ed by `consumer`, and be `next()`-ed / iterated by it. It may well be the case, but...

If it's just `await`-ed, then the last part could be:

`Awaitable[Any]`, if you actually await for something or

`Awaitable[None]`, if the callback doesn't return anything and you only expect to `await` it.

Note: your `consumer` isn't `async`. It will not really `await` your `function_`, but either `yield from` it, or do some `loop.run_until_complete()` or `.create_task()`, or `.ensure_future()`.

Comment: I was just looking for the definition of `Awaitable` thanks to your answer, I now know that's in `typing`. BTW, the issues mentioned were closed in 2021.

Answer (score 56):

You are looking for:

```
FuncType = Callable[[Any, Any], Awaitable[Any]]
def consumer(function_: FuncType = None):
    pass  # TODO: do stuff
```

Why is the type structured like that? If you declare a function `async`, what you actually do is wrap it in a new function with the given parameters, which returns a `Coroutine` (which is an `Awaitable`).

---

Since this might be relevant to some people who come here, this is an example of an `await`able function type with in and out typed:

```
OnAction = Callable[[Foo, Bar], Awaitable[FooBar]]
```

It is a function that takes `Foo`, `Bar` and returns a `FooBar`

Comment: when I try out  the `FuncType` you propose, mypy seems to be equally happy with normal functions as async functions.  so this type does not seem to constrain you to only `async def` style functions.

Comment: ah ok i think i see what's going on. this works only if your callbacks have good type hints themselves.  specifically, if they define their return types.  otherwise even a non-async function has return type `Any`, which mypy will say type checks against `Coroutine[Any]`.  leastways i think that's what's going on.

Comment: @hwjp yea, of course. `Coroutine` is just the return type of an async function. So if your function has no return type declared, it could secretly behave like an async one.

Comment: Type hints should use `Awaitable` instead of `Coroutine` - the relevant thing is almost always "can I use `await` on this?", not implementation details like whether you're looking at an awaitable defined with `async def` as opposed to some object with an `__await__` method or whatever.