# Typehinting async function and passing to asyncio.create_task

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

In my research, I see the general consensus for the correct way to typehint an async function is `Callable[..., Awaitable[Any]]`.

In Pycharm, I try this and have this issue when passing to `asyncio.create_task`

```py
import asyncio
from typing import Callable, Awaitable, Any

def fff(ccc: Callable[..., Awaitable[Any]]):
    return asyncio.create_task(ccc())
```

[image]

Is this an issue with Pycharm, or should I be typehinting my async functions another way?

Comment: your function does not return anything

Comment: fff? I'm just using that to wrap around the code to demonstrate the type hinting. I'm not concerned about that - it's ccc

Comment: Could you please show your `ccc` function? or at least the signature of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break things down to pieces:

1. When we declare an asynchronous function that returns some value - we basically create a function as this example shows (Python 3.11):

```py
async def ccc():
    return "Hello World"

type(ccc) # <--- function
```

2. This function **returns** an object of type **coroutine**

```py
async def ccc():
    return "Hello World"

type(ccc()) # <--- coroutine, not str!
```

That is because this asynchronous function needs to be **awaited** in order to really return what we've initially wanted it to return - a string.

Effectively, calling a coroutine inside an asynchronous function will not do anything as the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#awaitables) state:

> We say that an object is an awaitable object if it can be used in an await expression. Many asyncio APIs are designed to accept awaitables.

Meaning that your `ccc` function is indeed callable which gets some "%d" parameters (hence the ellipsis), which returns a coroutine.

So to say the least, the type hinting is something as such:

```py
Callable[..., Coroutine]
```

And you can be more explicit with the `Coroutine` as I don't know what `ccc` returns.

Moreover, I am not sure how you want to call `fff` as it is not asynchronous, you will need to make it such and await the `asyncio.create_task` as such:

```py
import asyncio
from typing import Callable, Coroutine


async def ccc():
    print("Hello")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("World")
    return 12345


async def fff(random_callable: Callable[..., Coroutine]):
    result = await asyncio.create_task(random_callable())
    print(f"{result=}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    el = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    el.run_until_complete(fff(ccc))
    el.close()
```

**Note:** I created `ccc` randomly for my own case of explanation, as you did not provide it in the question itself :-)

Comment: Right understood, thank you for the clarification. `ccc` was meant to be a generic `async def` function (like your example). `asyncio.create_task` not being awaited and `fff` not being `async` is because I was creating a minimal example of a background task (in actuality `ccc` the task will be garbage collected if I don't do anything with it). Edited OP so that `fff` returns it

Comment: But what I also wanted to know is why answers (and comments) such as this say you 'should' use Awaitable instead of Coroutine https://stackoverflow.com/a/59177557/5805389

Comment: In my example, `random_callable` is indeed a callable, and it returns a coroutine which is itself awaitable in the sense that "we can await it" - but the actual pythonic type of it is `Coroutine`. I would suggest reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36342899/asyncio-ensure-future-vs-baseeventloop-create-task-vs-simple-coroutine thread as it explains nicely the differences between coroutines, tasks, ensure_future, create_tasks etc... (we could change it to `random_callable: Callable[..., Awaitable]` and just await it directly: `result = await random_callable()`

Comment: According to docs, the typehint for `Coroutine` should have this form `Coroutine[YieldType, SendType, ReturnType]` like a Generator. Do you know why this is the case? Unless you are defining an async generator, I don't understand this. Maybe I'll open a new question if this isn't a simple one line answer

Comment: I think it should be another thread :-)

Comment: @Shuri2060 Here's a [GVR comment on Awaitable vs Coroutine](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3569). `async def`-ed functions have `send`, `throw` and `close` methods in addition to `__await__`, and they are required by `asyncio.create_task`. Check [good explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469060/python-native-coroutines-and-send), read the [PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0492/). Its interaction with generators [can be even more funny](https://peps.python.org/pep-0525/). And play in REPL, of course: `async def foo(): {yield|return} None; dir(foo())`